# Concatenating files with delimiter in for loop

Tags: shell-script, ls, for, postgresql

I'm loading data from the filesystem to postgres. I have 500 millions of single files, 1 json in each file.
In order to be more efficient with postgres I want to load those in batches not as single files. For now I have this loop:

```
time for i in datafiles/*; do   psql -c "\copy json_parts(json_data) FROM $i"& done
```

Could you please help me with adding "batch capabilities" here? I'm not proficient in bash. I suppose there is some kind of outer loop needed that is taking only let's say 40 files at a time and then adding delimiter between them so postgres knows those are separate rows?
I'm playing with

```
ls|head -$j| tail -40
```

as outer loop, but as said i'm not proficient...

Comment: What would the psql script look like with, say, 5 files?

Comment: I can do cat $i | psql ..etc. if in $i would contain 5 files